Intialize BaseModel attribute depending on other attribute
Assuming the following pydantic BaseModel:
class Zones(str, Enum):
    zone_a = 'zone_a'
    zone_b = 'zone_b'
    zone_c = 'zone_c'

class Vlan(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(title="the VLAN id")
    name: str = Field(title="the VLAN name")
    zone: Zones = Field(title="the security zone")

As a user, I only want to instantiate the class using the id attribute. Example:
my_vlan = Vlan(id=2001)

Of course, this throws a validation exception, because the mandatory fields name and zone are missing. I want these field to be populated by "some logic" as soon as the class is instanciated. The name is automatically set using: f'my_vlan{id}' and the zone is set by some integer range logic (if id > 10 and id < 100 then ...).
I'm confused with all the possible options like field_validators, model_validators or using an __init__ method in my class. Is there an elegant approach for this?
